# Standalone Android toolchain doesn't provide gdb binary

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb, remote-debugging

Android NDK, since 11 version, doesn't provide gdb binary. (NDK v10.e has it.)

How to debug native code via standalone toolchain that I use for build if standalone toolchain doesn't provide gdb binary ?

Do I have to build gdb from sources from google repository ?